# The difference between 時　and 時は

Tags: particles, particle-は

I know that it's correct to use は　after 時, and it's also correct to omit it. For example:

> 子供の **時**、よく海で泳ぎました。
>
> 子供の **時は**、よく海で泳ぎました。

How does the meaning of the sentence change when the particle is used and when it's not? This may be a slight change, but still.

Comment: Very similar to a question you asked last month: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/65466/omission-of-the-particle-%E3%81%AF

Comment: @BJCUAI Thank you! So, it's the same thing then... I've just come across the following sentence: 学生の時にもっと勉強しておけばよかったですよ。Here they use ni after toki. Is is the same as ... toki wa...?

Comment: Roughly similar to the difference between 'In my childhood' vs. 'As for my childhood'. As with most things it is not directly equivalent, but I think you get the nuance.

Comment: @BJCUAI yes, you have helped me a lot! Thank you very much!

Comment: `学生の時にもっと勉強しておけばよかったですよ。Here they use ni after toki. Is is the same as ... toki wa...?` >> 「学生の**時は**もっと勉強しておけばよかった」 sounds unnatural.

Comment: @Chocolate does it sound unnatural because if I use "wa," then it means "then I needed to study more, but now I don't"? If I mean exactly that, can I say "gakusei no toki wa..."?

Comment: No... You say 「～～ときに(or～～とき)…ておけばよかった」"I should have … / I regret that I didn't … when ~~ " eg 「安いときに買っておけばよかった」"I should have bought it when it was cheaper" (← In fact, I did NOT buy it.) but not 「安いとき**は** /安いときに**は**買っておけばよかった」. If you mean "I needed to study more when I was a student, but now I don't need to study hard anymore." (← In fact, I DID study.), you can say 「学生の時は、もっと勉強しないといけなかった。/勉強しなければならなかった。」

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 子供の**時**、よく海で泳ぎました。
>   子供の**時は**、よく海で泳ぎました。

You might say the latter to imply...

> "I used to swim in the sea in my childhood (*but now I don't anymore*)."

Here, the は is functioning as the contrastive particle (対比の「は」).

---

You might also say the latter when responding to a question...

> "What did you often do in your childhood?"
>   -- "*In my childhood*, I often swam in the sea."

Here, the は is functioning as the topic particle (主題の「は」).

---

You'd say the former to just neutrally state that you would often swim in the sea in your childhood.